# Creating new rows from a single new entry in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, one-to-many

**Background:** I have two tables linked with a one-to-many relationship.

1. *Table1* contains static life-history information for a single individual (e.g. name, sex, Mother). *ID* is the primary key in *Table1*.
2. *Table2* contains life history events for every individual in Table1. There are multiple life history events for every individual. Most individuals have the 6 standard life history events, but some individuals may have additional life history events. *ID* and *EventCode* are combined for the primary key in Table2.

I have accomplished linking the tables and creating a data entry form that presents the data for a single individual from *Table1* and *Table2*. Adding a new record for *Table2's* additional life history trait is also functioning.

**Question:** I would like to set the form up so that when a new individual is added to *Table1*, *Table2* automatically presents the standard 6 life history rows. So, a single entry in *Table1* would create 6 new rows with the standard event codes, prompting those entering data to fill in those six rows.

Can this be done? How?

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag but please describe architecture. Do you have linked MySQL tables in an MS Access .mdb/.accdb app or did you mistakenly tag that DBMS?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're correct. The MySQL tag was a mistake. I am working in directly in a MS-Access database and creating forms for data entry.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are called triggers.  The documentation for MySql can be found here: [MySql trigger documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html)

Examples including one for inserting into another table can be found here: [Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "TRIGGER", here's a document for that:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html

```
CREATE TRIGGER table1_insert_LifeEvents AFTER INSERT ON table1
       FOR EACH ROW SET 
BEGIN
insert into table_LifeEvents (column1,column2);
insert into table_LifeEvents (column1,column2);
insert into table_LifeEvents (column1,column2);
insert into table_LifeEvents (column1,column2);
insert into table_LifeEvents (column1,column2);
insert into table_LifeEvents (column1,column2);
END;
```